# Correct approach for implementing vertical scrolling with UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I know that I asked a question a few minutes ago, but I want to make a few points clearer before asking for the community's help. I'm new to iOS development, close to finishing my first app. The only thing standing in my way is this UIScrollView. I simply do not understand it, and could use your help.

This is in the detail view controller of a drill-down app with a tab bar. I have approximately 8 fields (for things like phone numbers and such) drawing from a .plist. Obviously, those take up enough room that I could use a little extra real estate. I would guess that it needs to be about the size of two views vertically, but I do not understand how to allocate that sort of space to a UIScrollView. Some tutorials I have read say that you don't even need to define it in the header, which I doubt and do not understand. Additionally, I do not understand how to simply get the app to smoothly scroll up-and down only. Apple's examples have constant move cycles that flip between horizontal pictures.

I doubt it makes very much a difference, but I have an image that is in the background. I'm going to load the view on top of that.

My question is broad, so I don't expect you to take the time to sit down and write out all of the code for me (and I wouldn't ask you to). Just an outline of quick, helpful tips would help me understand how to get this view to load in the context of my project.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fairly simple. Add a UIScrollView to your view. Add your fields and such to the scrollview. In viewDidLoad or somewhere similar, you need to set the contentSize on your scrollview. This is the "virtual" area that will be scrollable. This will generally be larger than the frame of the scrollview. In your case, you indicated it should be roughly double the width.

For instance, if you had a scrollview with a view inside, and you wanted to make sure the entire view is visible via scrolling:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.frame.size;
```

Comment: Alright, if View is Scroll view's parent, how am I supposed to add content to it (probably a stupid question)

Answer (score 2):

```
//setting scrollview zoom level
    self._scrollview.minimumZoomScale=0.5;

    self._scrollview.maximumZoomScale=6.0;

    self._scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,500 );
```

you have to outlet scroll view in .h class and @property @synthesis this scroll view.then you can able to scroll up and down,if u want only vertical scrolling ,then u have to go to interface builder and uncheck the horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a few settings for your scrollview to limit the scrolling to horizontal or vertical. A few important ones are:

```
// pseudcode here, start typing "[scrollView " then press escape to get a intelli-sense of all // the things you can set for the scrollview.

// values could be YES/NO or TRUE/FALSE, I can't remember which one but 
// I think it's YES/NO. Once you start scrolling, the phone will determine
// which way you're scrolling then lock it to that direction
[scrollView setDirectionalLockEnabled:YES];

// when you slide the view, if enough of the next part of the view is visible, 
// the scrollview will snap or bounce the scrollview to fit this new "page".
// think of swiping feature to navigate the iPhone home screens 
// to show different "pages" of iphone apps
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

// as a safe guard, make sure the width of your scrollview fits snuggly with the content 
// it is trying to display. If the width is more than necessary to display your table of 
// data vertically, sometimes the scrollview will cause the 
// horizontal scrolling that you don't want to happen and you get bi-directional scrolling
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the content size of UIScrollView after adding all the controls/button/textfields etc. for example you add 10 textfields in UIScrollview then content size of UIScrollView will be

```
lastTextField.frame.origin.y+lastTextField.frame.size.height+20; 20 is for margin.
```

That's it let me know if you want to know something more related to your app.

Comment: How am I supposed to add all of the content to the Scroll View considering its size? Is there a specific way to do this in interface builder? (Probably a really stupid question)

Comment: Yes you can do it also in interface builder. That is a little bit tricky. First change your default UIView's class to UIScrollView. then remove the top status bar by setting it to none in properties of UIViewController in IB. then drag as much as you want place all the components then again reduce view height to 460 aur 416 depends if you are using navigation controller or not. Then in view Did load set content size of UIScrollView.